# OSError: [Error 1] Operation not permitted shutil.move

Tags: python, linux, shutil

So I'm trying to copy a file from my boot drive to an external using python. Because of this, os.rename is not an option (I would get a cross device error). I decided to try and use shutil.move but then this throws a OSError 1, claiming that the operation is not permitted on it's internal call of os.chmod. The interesting thing is that the directory it is moving to has  permissions 777. The call is as follows:

```
if hasattr(f.file,'name'):
                    move(f.file.name,path)
```

The full stack trade is as follows.

```
[08/Sep/2014:00:49:36] HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 670
, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 2
17, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 61
, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/btsync/BitTorrentSyncWeb/py/main.py", line 129, in upload
    move(f.file.name,path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 301, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 100, in copystat
    os.chmod(dst, mode)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/bakery/Dump/ck.gif'
```

The permissions are shown below

```
$ls -l /mnt/bakery/
    drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 32768 Sep  8 01:30 Dump
$ls -l /mnt/bakery/Dump |grep ck.gif
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1017711 Sep  8 00:49 ck.gif
```

Comment: Are you asking how to move it without changing permissions, or how to make moving-wiht-changing-permissions work?

Comment: I'm just asking why I can't move this file, and how to fix it. I should be able to move it.

Comment: Well, have you tried doing these commands in the shell? If you can reproduce this there, then this is a perfect question for SuperUser (but not a good question for Stack Overflow). If the `chmod` works in the shell but not in `shutil.move`, then you have a good SO question… but first call the individual methods in Python to make see if you can get more information. But I'm willing to bet that it's the former, and you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: Got it. Yeah it doesn't work in a shell either. Poo. I didn't realize that was the problem. I'll try some workarounds and then post on SU. Thanks.

EDIT: did some poking around, turns out the issue is that my HDD is formatted as FAT32, and thus can't use chmod. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure your drive has a format that linux can chmod. FAT32 is not one of these.